# will msvc compiler optimize " if (true): statement " to just " statement " in release mode?

Tags: c++

To check for nullptr I am doing this:

```
    template <class PointerType>
    bool nullptrCheck(PointerType ptr)
    {
#ifdef NDEBUG
        return true;
#else
        return ptr != nullptr;
#endif
    }
```

Say that I used it like this:

```
int main()
{
    int* a = getA();
    if (nullptrCheck(a))
    {
        something(a);
    }
}
```

In release mode, will the compiler turn it into following ?

```
int main()
{
    int* a = getA();
    something(a);
}
```

Also is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Only way to know for certain is to compile it and check the assembly code.

Comment: Would have been quicker to ask compiler explorer (/look at the disassembly), but yes. Even a basic optimizing compiler should be able to do this.

Comment: A decent compiler should optimize `nullptrCheck` away, yes. If you want to be sure, set up a sample project and examine the assembly generated. [At least one compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/arzfxbxjx) optimizes the whole thing away to nothing.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Compiling it and checking the assembly code cannot tell you things for certain when it is possible the compiler will change in future updates or when different circumstances in the program may produce different results. This particular situation may be simple enough to come to some confidence in the result, except that OP has not even stated that `nullptrCheck` is defined in the same translation unit as its use. But situations involving more complicated language semantics may not be so clear, and bug fixes in the compiler, changes in the language, and such may change things.

Comment: Is the definition of `nullptrCheck` visible to the compiler at the call `nullptrCheck(a)`?That is, is it defined above the call in the same translation unit and not in another unit or below the call?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's a template, it kinda has to be.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: You can declare a template without defining it and can instantiate and define it in another translation unit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's defined in a different fine and I include it where I need it. Wouldn't it be a compiling errror if it wasent visible to the compiler?

Comment: @EricPostpischil What other means do you have in mind for investigating compiler optimizations, if not examining the compiler output? Yes, of course things may change in the future (hopefully for the better, not worse) - is that a good reason to avoid examining the behavior as it exists now? Note that the question is not about the observable behavior of the program (where one could appeal to the letter of the standard), but about implementation details.

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes: If “fine” means “file,” and, particularly, a different source file that is compiled separately, then no, you cannot rely on the call to be optimized to a constant `true` unless MSVC is doing some cross-module optimization I have not heard. If it is defined in a different header file that is included in the source file that uses it, then the compiler should see it, and I would expect this to optimize to a constant `true`. No, it is not a compilation error for the definition not to be visible where a function is used. Identifiers with external linkage are linked by the linker.

Comment: As an aside, that's pretty soft as far as debug only checks go. A no-op at debug time? That feels backwards. Why not `assert(a); something(a);` ?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Learn about language semantics and consider factors that may interfere with the optimization, such as, as I pointed out, the fact the definition may not be visible to the compiler at the call. Experimenting with how the compiler behaves may be useful **after** one has determined the proposed experiment is a representative sample and properly accounts for complications that could be caused by circumstances. Or, if it is essential to the product, another solution is to incorporate checks of the optimization in the product build process.

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes: Please clarify: Is the definition of `nullptrCheck` in a different source file that is compiled separately from the source file where it is called?

Comment: @EricPostpischil No.

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes: Okay, is the definition of `nullptrCheck` in a header file that is included in the source file from where it is called, before the call?

Comment: @EricPostpischil You can declare a template without defining it, but this function is not defined this way.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: You have not seen all the code. Certainly `getA` and `something` are elided or substitutes, and we do not know what else OP as omitted, such as a header file that declares `nullptrCheck` separately from the definition. That is why I **asked** them what the situation is instead of jumping to conclusions. To do engineering, ascertain the facts.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't need to see all of the OP's code; I've seen enough of other people's code. I know a unique snowflake when I see one. This one isn't.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: To do engineering, ascertain the facts.

Comment: Have you tried it on Compiler Explorer?